# Como parar handler dentro de uma asynctask

Tags: java, android

Possuo a seguinte asynctask, a qual contem um handler dentro dela, porem quando saio da activity fecho a async porem algumas vezes o handler continua chamando a async depois de fechada. Não da crash no aplicativo mas fica mandando logs como se estivesse dando erro, segue abaixo a async

```
public class PostImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, PutObjectResult> {

    public PostImageAsyncTask() {
        super();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // before making http calls

    }

    @Override
    protected PutObjectResult doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            return amazonS3Client.putObject(por);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PutObjectResult result) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            if (result != null) {
                showAndHideLoad(false);
                if(step == 0) {
                    picture = new Picture(amazonUrl, null);
                } else if(step == 1) {
                    documentIDs = new DocumentIDs(amazonUrl,null);
                } else if( step == 2){
                    documentIDs.setBackURL(amazonUrl);
                }

                if ((snackbar != null && snackbar.isShown())) {
                    snackbar.dismiss();
                }
                send_continue();
            } else {

                if (RECONECT_TIME_DELAY < MAX_TIME_DELAY) {
                    if ((snackbar == null || !snackbar.isShown())) {
                        isClicked=false;
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayoutView, getString(R.string.snackbar_internet_fail), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
                        snackbar.setAction("Cancelar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                //
                            }
                        });
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            RECONECT_TIME_DELAY = RECONECT_TIME_DELAY * 2;
                            postImageAsyncTask.cancel(true);
                            postImageAsyncTask = new PostImageAsyncTask();
                            postImageAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                        }
                    }, RECONECT_TIME_DELAY);
                }
            }
        } else {
            postImageAsyncTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AsyncTasks não foram feitas para se combinar com Handler. Você deveria fazer as várias tentativas de conexão em doInBackground() e a cada tentativa falhada chamar publishProgress(), o que faz onProgressUpdate() ser chamado (nele você pode atualizar os elementos da tela).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `AsyncTasks` não foram feitas para se combinar com `Handler`. É possível fazer o que você está querendo (atualizar elementos da tela cada vez que ocorre um erro durante a conexão com a Amazon) somente com uma `AsyncTask`, sem precisar de um `Handler` para isso.

`AsyncTasks` permitem atualizar a tela no meio da execução de uma tarefa assíncrona, bastando para isso chamar o método `publishProgress()`.

No método `doInBackground()` faça um loop que tenta se conectar à Amazon um certo número de vezes. Cada vez que a conexão falhar, chame o método `publishProgress()`. Isso resultará no método `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate()` ser chamado, e dentro dele você pode atualizar a tela conforme desejado.

Deixe o método `onPostExecute()` para a situação em que a conexão foi bem-sucedida.